# Shared root item between two QAbstractItemModels

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have a tree data structure defined by a root node and several branches.  I want to display one specific branch in one `QTreeView` and all other branches in another `QTreeView`.  My plan is to use two different models (derived from `QAbstractItemModel`), one for each of the views, with the root item shared between the two models.  Each model would be responsible for displaying the correct branch of the root item.  However, I have not seen anything in the Qt documentation about sharing root items between models, and I'm a bit worried that this is a dangerous thing to do (e.g. not thread-safe).  Has anyone done this before, and, did it work?  If there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do, I'm all ears.

Comment: The meaning of Qt model/view architecture (MVC) is having one model and multiple views. Why don't you simply one model and show different branches in different views using `QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex()`.

Comment: I never knew about `setRootIndex`.  That's exactly what I need.  Thanks.